# React-Bootstrap styles not loading with storybook

Tags: webpack, react-bootstrap, storybook

I started using storybook for my react-typescript project recently and ran into below issues:

1. My react-bootstrap components do not have style. The components are
   loaded but without styles.I tried using the style-loader and css
   loader in custom webpack config but did not work.
2. I am importing some local fonts, but the fonts are always loaded
   inside the Fonts folder. Is there a way to load the fonts in
   /static/fonts directory? I am using file loader to load the fonts.
3. I have a globalStyles.tsx file and a iconStyles.tsx file which I
   would like to include globally in the storyboard iframe. What would
   be the best way to that?

I am running storybook locally on localhost.

Below is my main.js with custom webpack configuration :

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/stories/**/*.stories.[tj]s','../src/stories/**/*.stories.tsx'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-actions', '@storybook/addon-links'],
  webpackFinal: async config => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /(?<!.*\.test)\.(ts|tsx)$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: require.resolve('ts-loader'),
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.ttf$|\.woff$|\.eot$|\.otf$/,
      use: [
        {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          outputPath: '/static/fonts',
        },

        },
      ]

    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    }
    );
    config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx');
    return config;
  },
};
```

Comment: Any luck with this? Have tried all the answers but no luck.

Answer (score 9):

You should import both Bootstrap CSS and JS in `.storybook/preview.js`:

```js
import 'relative/path/to/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'relative/path/to/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
```

Just tested with storybook/react-6.3.7 and bootstrap-5.1.0.

Comment: Good one, very simple solution :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a formal answer but perhaps storybook cannot identify by default that bootstrap is being used.

A quick workaround that I'm doing is to add the following line **import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';** on the **stories.js** files. It allows me to visualize my reactrsap components with their proper styling.

Answer (score 5):

All you have to do is import your css file in `.storybook/preview.js`, as [mentioned in the docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/styling-and-css#importing-css-files).

Comment: Not sure why this is the most upvoted answer. This is apparent and does not answer the question of how to get bootstrap styles working with story book.

Comment: I found this question precisely because I tried to have my own react-boostrap components in storybook and they lacked the styles. the answer I gave was suggested to me in the storybook discord channels. it did solve my issue.